# ActionBar in Android overrides the BottomNavigation

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When trying to change an icon to a downloaded drawable (or actually changing to any other icon during runtime), the icon changes once on the ActionBar.

I actually want to remove the ActionBar and leave only the bottomnav (tabs) for navigation, yet whatever i'm doing the icon changes only on the ActionBar.

The item inside bottom_nav_menu.xml:

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_notifications"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

The code that changes the icon:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bottom_nav_menu, menu);
    menu.getItem(2).setIcon(this.bitmap_pic);

    Log.e(TAG, "Icon Changed");
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

The result - Icon stays blank on BottomNav but appears on the ActionBar.

[image]

Expected result: BottomNav icon will be the image that shown on the top right.

Thanks

**EDIT!**

Issue was fixed after inflating the main_activity layout that contains the BottomNavView

Now the problem the picture isn't showing properly, attached a screenshot (Image is grey instead of showing the icon like in the ActionBar in the first picture):

[image]

**Edit 2**

Icon is still grey instead of showing the bitmap picture.
Added:

```
MenuItemCompat.setIconTintMode(bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2), PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
```

But it still shows up like in the picture below

[image]

**Edit 3**

Fixed the issue using:

```
        bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: Important to mention, also setTitle does not work on the BottomNav. yet setBackground works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `onPrepareOptionsMenu` invoked for bottom navigation bar.

You should have to update navigation menu icon from `onCreate` method of that Activity.

Refer below code,

```
val menu = navigation.menu
val menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_notifications) // find particular menu-item using its ID.
menuItem?.icon = this.bitmap_pic
```

Solution for Gray icon tint,
add below line.

```
MenuItemCompat.setIconTintMode(menuItem, PorterDuff.Mode.DST)
```

Comment: Actually found the issue,         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) fixed the issue. I've edited the question

Comment: A Still didn't work, updated my question